# The Atlas system word addresses

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware

I'm reading about the Atlas operating system and I came across this:

> The Atlas system used a British computer with 48-bit words. Addresses were 24 bits but were encoded in decimal, which allowed 1 million words to be addressed.

Why is it 1 million here if it's encoded in decimal?

Comment: Can you add attribution for the source where you encountered this?  See our guidelines on the expectations: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like by "encoded in decimal" what they mean is binary coded decimal (BCD), which is a format which uses 4 bits to encode the numbers 0-9.  Obviously this wastes a little, as those 4 bits could also encode 10-15, but that is sacrificed to make a 1:1 mapping between groups of bits and digits of a number in base 10

24-bits divided by 4 bits per base 10 digit yields 6 base 10 digits.  6 digits is enough to count from 0 to 999,999, hence a million adddresses.